# Can you tripleclick() a text to select a paragraph in python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, copy-paste

Can you tripleclick() a text to select the paragraph in python selenium? Or doubleclick()? And then copy-paste it with ActionChains? Without having to ctrl+a.

Comment: Have you tried ```double_click``` from ActionChains?

Comment: Code trials please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
actionChains = ActionChains(driver)

actionChains.double_click("element variable name").perform()
```